# I have json data and want to download/export in excel using React Native on iOS app. How do I go about it?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, xlsx

In android, I was able to do the following and the excel file was available under Downloads/Documents, I am not able to achieve the same thing on an iOS device. Even though I can download the file, I can not find it anywhere on the device. Thank you in advance!

```
 let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    let ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataToExport);
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Users");
    const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { type: "binary", bookType: "xlsx" });

       RNFS.writeFile(
       RNFS.{placeholder_directory} + `/${reportName}.xlsx`,
       wbout,
       "ascii"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`DownloadDirectoryPath` is only available on Android. Use e.g. `LibraryDirectoryPath` on iOS.

> DownloadDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the download directory (on android only)

See more options [Constants](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Even if I use the paths like LibraryDirectoryPath, DocumentDirectoryPath, etc., where are the files downloaded on the phone actually?